# Calling flask via javascript run on an https external site

Tags: javascript, python, flask

There is an external site that runs https. I have a UI based "server" that I can run javascript from.

I want to have that site send me a `XMLHttpRequest()` via my javascript running on their site to my Flask_Restful running elsewhere.

This code works, but only on http sites. Their site is http**s**.
I am currently running this code on the chrome console when on their site.

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    
xhttp.open("PUT", "http://[my_server]:5000/todos/todo3", true);`
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "task": "new task2"}));
```

So I get the error:

```
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

If I run it with https I get the error:

```
OPTIONS https://9[my_flask_server]:5000/todos/todo3 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

My Flask server also prints out:

```
code 400, message Bad request syntax ('\x16...
```

How do I enable my flask site to allow this SSL call?

I have enabled CORS like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)
```

**EDIT 1**

I am trying to add ssl capabilities to my server.

I have made a host.cert file and a host.key file by using this:

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > host.key
chmod 400 host.key
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -sha1 -days 365 -key host.key -out host.cert
```

source: https://serverfault.com/questions/224122/what-is-crt-and-key-and-how-can-i-generate-them

And I updated my Flask app.py such that the top looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from OpenSSL import SSL
context = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
context.use_privatekey_file('host.key')
context.use_certificate_file('host.cert')

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)
```

source: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/

When I run python app.py it errors out now.

Current error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 72, in <module>
    app.run(host="[my_server]", port="5000", ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 841, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 742, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 702, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 596, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 528, in __init__
    self.socket = ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_side=True)
AttributeError: 'OpenSSL.SSL.Context' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'
```

**EDIT 2: (didn't work)**

```
sudo pip install 'Werkzeug==0.9.6'
```

Changes the issue to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 851, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 724, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 464, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 328, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
Logged from file _internal.py, line 87
```

**EDIT 3: PROGRESS**

Using just

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
...
```

and

```
...
if __name__ == '__main__':
     context = ('host.crt', 'host.key')
     app.run(host...
```

Has changed the console side error from:

```
OPTIONS https://[my_flask_server]:5000/todos/todo3 net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

to

```
OPTIONS https://[my_flask_server]:5000/todos/todo3 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

**EDIT 3**

At this point its just browser related security checks since my ssl certificate is not recognized / weak.  I think I've got it working as well as I can, Im gonna try and get it more authorized i guess?

Comment: You need to have your Flask server actually talk HTTPS. For debugging purposes you could set up the Flask development server to [directly serve HTTPS](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/111/), but for production you'll want to have HTTPS termination done by a Web server like Nginx or Apache httpd.

Comment: @LukasGraf thanks for the advice, would I have to get into contact with the site that I am doing https with? In other words: would my HTTPS credentials have to be approved by the site hosting the JS?

Comment: I don't think so, as far as I understand you should be able to solve everything on your end: If your backend app and and their JS app were to be server under the same domain, you would need their SSL certificate - but I'm assuming that's not the case, since you mention CORS.